# Program does not read string correctly

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I recognize the user's appdata folder and add the name of the vbs script there

```
SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(NULL, CSIDL_APPDATA, &pAPPData);
SHGetPathFromIDList(pAPPData, szAPPData);//appdata path 
std::string cometa = szAPPData + slashrat += vbsname;//fullpath
LPSTR scometa = const_cast<char*>(cometa.c_str());//string to LPSTR
```

then i'm trying to run script using ShellExecute or CreateProcces(the script has the WORKING code),but all without success.

```
ShellExecute(NULL,"open", scometa, NULL, NULL, SW_NORMAL);
```

Then I tried adding the script launch to the registry:

```
_TCHAR* szTestString = 0;
szTestString = new _TCHAR[cometa.size()];
strcpy(szTestString, cometa.c_str());
TCHAR szPath[] = _T("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\");
HKEY hKey;
if (RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, szPath, 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_VOLATILE, KEY_WRITE, NULL, &hKey, NULL) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    MessageBox(NULL, "openning data error", "error", NULL);
    return 1;
}

if (RegSetValueEx(hKey, _T("Test string"), 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE*)szTestString, sizeof(szTestString)) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    MessageBox(NULL, "writing data error", "error", NULL);
    return 2;
}

if (RegCloseKey(hKey) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    MessageBox(NULL, "closing data error", "error", NULL);
    return 3;
};
```

and also unsuccessfully,
the value is written to the registry: C:\U".
Or even random unreadable characters(if not converting to TCHAR)
Need,help;).I've been working on this problem for 3 days.
Btw, if i using `system(scometa)`, the launch works fine,but the console constantly gets out of the way

Comment: `sizeof(szTestString)` -- This does not do what you think it does.  This is no different than `sizeof(_TCHAR *)`.  If that string had a million characters, the `sizeof(_TCHAR*)` will still either be 4 or 8, depending whether this is a 32-bit or 64-bit program.

Comment: `strcpy(szTestString, cometa.c_str());` only makes sense when `_TCHAR` is `char`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I find the more "to the right" code is formatted and is hidden is a post, the more likely the problem is [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65083936/program-does-not-read-string-correctly#comment115062855_65083936).   Best to format code with respect to the presentation.

Comment: First, you need to tell us whether this is a Unicode or MBCS application.  A `TCHAR` is different, depending on the character set type being used.

Comment: MBCS application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YAAAAAAY,i fixed it.
1.converting string to char*

```
char* ccometa = new char[cometa.length() + 1];
strcpy(ccometa, cometa.c_str());
```

2. converting char* to tchar

```
TCHAR Tccometa[512];
_tcscpy(Tccometa, A2T(ccometa));
```

Profit:D

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.